# matching escape charactres using like operator in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to match the string having escape characters with particular column in a table.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE 'MESSRESTAURANGER AB\\MESSVEGEN 1\\STOCKH';
```

Though there is matching data in table, query result is empty set. But the same query works fine in oracle. What is the issue with mysql?

Answer (score 0):

You miss `%`:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE '%MESSRESTAURANGER AB\\MESSVEGEN 1\\STOCKH%';
```

But it should work without escaping:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE '%MESSRESTAURANGER AB\MESSVEGEN 1\STOCKH%';
```

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7ba59/2

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE n LIKE '%MESSRESTAURANGER AB\\\\\\\\MESSVEGEN 1\\\\\\\\STOCKH%'
```

> Because MySQL uses C escape syntax in strings (for example, “\n” to
>   represent a newline character), you must double any “\” that you use
>   in LIKE strings. For example, to search for “\n”, specify it as “\n”.
>   To search for “\”, specify it as `\\\\`; this is because the
>   backslashes are stripped once by the parser and again when the pattern
>   match is made, leaving a single backslash to be matched against.

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ac46b/9

Comment: this 'MESSRESTAURANGER AB\\MESSVEGEN 1\\STOCKH' is the exact data i want to match.